# FreePBX / Asterisk queue leastrecent Breaks on transfer

Tags: asterisk

I am running into some weird issue's with queue's, It almsot seem's as if when you transfer, or go on hold it does not reset the lastcall time

Scenario –

John is on a call with a customer.

Mary is sitting available waiting for calls.

John finishes with her customer, transfers her customer to an external number, puts herself in ready, and gets the next call that comes in.

Mary is still sitting available.

After speaking with the team, they tell me that this is how it always works.  If you’re on a call and you transfer your caller away you’re automatically put back into the queue as the person to get the next call.  So, given this information, Mary could sit in ready status for two hours and not get a call if everything was timed just right and all of John’s calls were transfers.

This shouldn’t function this way.  It should be the other way around.  The next call should always go to the agent that has been available the longest.

Let me know what you think.

Asterisk version
Asterisk 1.8.11-cert10 built by root @ 89-139-19-10.digium.internal on a x86_64 running Linux on 2013-01-02 22:24:23 UTC

FreePBX Base Version: 2.10.0rc1
FreePBX Framework Version:
FreePBX Core Version: 2.10.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed with priority. You need setup context for return after transfer, in which you have put max priority and put again into queue.

It is hard to say how it exactly have look, but i am sure any asterisk developer can do that.

See examples on bottom of this page:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+features.conf